# How to convert an array in C# .net to ListPoint for calling ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: .netlink

I have a two-dimensional array in C# (using .Netlink)

```
double[][] rho
```

The values of the array change dynamically as it represents some process in time.

I have tested the following code to make sure 3D Graphics will work normally:

```
try
       {
           MathKernel k = new MathKernel(ml);
           k.CaptureGraphics = true;
           k.GraphicsFormat = "JPEG";
             string command = @"Show[ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 
0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}]]]";
           k.Compute(command);
           pictureBox1.Image = k.Graphics[0];
       }
       catch (Exception ee)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
       }
```

How can I change the command variable, so I could call ListPointPlot3D for the array in question? Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps someone will come up with something more concise.

```
try
       {
           double[][] rho = new double[4][] { new double[] { 0.0, 0.8, -0.8, 0.4 }, new double[] { 0.8, 0.9, -1.0, -0.5 }, new double[] { 0.9, 0.1, -0.3, -1.0 }, new double[] { 0.1, -0.8, 0.7, -0.5 } };

           var res = rho
               .Where(inner => inner != null) // Cope with uninitialised inner arrays.
               .Select(inner => inner.ToList()) // Project each inner array to a List<double>
               .ToList(); // Materialise the IEnumerable<List<double>> to List<List<double>>

           string str = "{";
           foreach (var a in res)
           {
               str += "{";
               foreach (double b in a)
                   str += b.ToString() + ", ";
               str += "}, ";
           }
           str += "}";
           str = str.Replace(", }", "}");

           MathKernel k = new MathKernel(ml);
           k.CaptureGraphics = true;
           k.GraphicsFormat = "JPEG";
           string command = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "Show[ListPointPlot3D[", str, "]]");
           k.Compute(command);
           pictureBox1.Image = k.Graphics[0];
       }
       catch (Exception ee)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
       }
```

Comment: I mark this as an accepted. This code works perfectly for me even for the array with more than 100 nodes. Thank you!